# Obtain width and place inside css background image url

Tags: html, url

I have a css background-url inside my HTML as follows:

`http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/500`

the HTML background-url is for a mobile device, so I need to use dynamic widths. What I need is a method to obtain the width of the device and dynamically place inside that background-url.

Not quite sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be with Javascript.

`document.getElementById("YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/" + screen.width + ")";`

This will set YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE's background to the URL `http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/` and then append the screen width in pixels to the URL.

Replace `YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE` with the actual element ID, and drop this into your body.

If it is a background for the body, you can use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementById`, thus it becomes

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/" + screen.width + ")";`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS3 `@media` rule. You can find a toturial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) or [here for the full reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

But basicly, you can use something like this:

```
body{
    background-url: url('http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/500')
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-url: url('http://something.else/');
    }
}
```

In the example above, the default background url is 
http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/500, but if the screen width is smaller than 400px, it will change to http://something.else/.

I hope this answerd your question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background: url('http://host/services/resizeimage/187261/width/500') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

That ensures that the background image will always cover the thing, and rather than making it slow using dynamic web changes that sometimes don't load first try. This also ensures that at the same time, it won't look clunky by maintaining somewhat of an aspect ratio.